# How can I make the first two columns and rows of my table sticky?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid, sticky

I am working to create a master gradebook application but I am needing help with CSS formatting. I have run into a problem that I am not sure how to fix:

1. I want the first two rows of the table to be "frozen" as well as the first two columns to be "frozen." I have this halfway working, but as you can see below, the second column slides on top of the first column. What is causing this?
2. Why is the "X%" under the first grade (in this case, BOTR Questions 11/12) colored in as teal? Why is CSS detecting this as `tr th:first-child`?

```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 65px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100vh - 65px);
     background-color: #FCFCFC;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-areas:
       "title"}

   .title {grid-area: title}

   .master {
     grid-area: modules;
     overflow-x: scroll;}

   table {border-collapse: collapse}

   th, td {
     max-width: 110px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;}

   th {
     z-index: 1;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0; left: 0;
     background-color: white;
     overflow: hidden;}

   tr th:first-child {
     z-index: 2;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
     background-color: cyan;}

   tr td:first-child, tr td:nth-child(2) {
     z-index: 1;
     position: sticky;
     left: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     max-width: fit-content !important;
     background-color: orange;}

   td input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     background-color: pink;
     padding: 0px;}

   th select {
     outline: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid lightgray}

   .assign {
     padding: 6px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: space-between;}

   .assign .due {
     font-size: 11px;
     color: darkgray;}

   .assign .title {
     font-size: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #581F98}

   .studentInfo {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 6px 12px 6px 6px;}

   .studentInfo img {
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     clip-path: circle();}

   .red {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: red;}

   .gray {
     width: 100%; height: 100%;
     background-color: lightgray;}

  .score {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class='master'>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th colspan='2' rowspan='2'>
              <select>
                <option>Reading</option>
                <option>Social Studies</option>
              </select>
              <select>
                <option>Week 1</option>
                <option>Week 2</option>
              </select>
            </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>10/06 to 10/13</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 11/12</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>10/06 to 10/08</span>
                  <span class='title'>TS Flipbook: Cause/Effect</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/28 to 10/01</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 9/10</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/30 to 10/01</span>
                  <span class='title'>TS: Compare & Contrast</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/21 to 09/27</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 7/8</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/15 to 09/20</span>
                  <span class='title'>TS Flipbook: Sequence</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/13 to 09/17</span>
                  <span class='title'>TS Flipbook: Description</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/07 to 09/13</span>
                  <span class='title'>Starving Context Clues</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/08 to 09/13</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 5/6</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/30 to 09/07</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 3/4</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>09/02 to 09/03</span>
                  <span class='title'>Profile: John Smith</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/31 to 09/03</span>
                  <span class='title'>Susan Constant vs England</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/23 to 08/31</span>
                  <span class='title'>BOTR Questions 1/2</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/23 to 08/27</span>
                  <span class='title'>Character Traits</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/19 to 08/24</span>
                  <span class='title'>Buckle Down PreTest</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/17 to 08/23</span>
                  <span class='title'>Roanoke Cornell Notes</span>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class='assign'>
                  <span class='due'>08/16 to 08/20</span>
                  <span class='title'>Roanoke Story Map</span>
                </div>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
              <th>X%</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/teachers/2.jpg'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/teachers/3.jpg'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/teachers/4.jpg'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/default.png'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>
              <td>
                <div class='studentInfo'>
                  <img src='../../resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
                  <span>John Doe</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>X%</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score gray'>X</td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td><td><div class='score'><input type='text'></div></td></tr>  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem lies in your `:first-child` and `:nth-child` selectors.
2. your selector is: in every row, the first `th` and the X is your first `th`.

If you are using position sticky, you have to define where it should stick to. I wrapped the first two rows in `thead` so I don't have to get the height of the first child.

On the second column, I defined it to stick 95px to the left, that's the width of the first column.

So I created a working minimal Example:

```css
.outer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table{
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
thead{
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
}
tr td:nth-child(1),
tr td:nth-child(2),
tr th:nth-child(1),
tr th:nth-child(2){
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
tr th:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(2){
  left: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
        <th>sticky</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>sticky</d>
      <td>sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
      <td>non sticky</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: "On the second column, I defined it to stick 95px to the left, that's the width of the first column."  - what would I do when I am not sure what the width of the first column will be? That's why i have the width of the first column set to "fit-content"

Comment: You can get the width with JS and then add the left property dynamically.
Or instead of using two columns, you can use only one column and put the content inside two divs inside that column.